# How to solve this 3 use case without database?

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, data-structures

I have Merchant_Id, Merchant_details, Shop_Id and are have category.

- If I create a HashTable with < Merchant_Id , Merchant_details > The retrieval of Merchant_details will be easy for a given Merchant_Id.
- The Shop_Id can be encapsulated inside the Merchant_details, so I can retrieve the list of shop for a Merchant_Id.
- If I need to list of merchants for a specific category, for example list of merchants in 'restaurant' or 'sports'. And I don't want to iterate through the entire list of items to find the category.

How can I incorporate all the three in single structure without database.

Comment: The easiest thing to do is create the objects based on what they would be if they were database tables.

Comment: Where is category stored?

Comment: I initially planned to store that in Merchant_details, but to list all the Merchant_Id's based on specific category ..I need to iterate through the entire list, which is not a good solution and costly

Comment: why downvote that question? That question is formulated clear enough, and even has relevance for [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping]  (ORM)

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion:
Create a structure with Merchant_Id, Merchant_Details and Shop_Id.
Put them into a `std::vector`.
Create an empty `std::map<Merchant_ID, unsigned int>`.

Iterate through the vector, adding elements to the map:

```
  merchant_id_map[vector[i].Merchant_ID] = i;
```

This is called an index table.
Create one for the other fields as well.

When you need to search by Merchant_Id, use the `merchant_id_map` to get the index into the vector:

```
  unsigned int vector_index = merchant_id_map[merchant_id];
  record = database_vector[vector_index];
```

Comment: Hey Thomas MAtthews, Now How will I list based on category ? My solution was HashTable with < Merchant_Id , Merchant_details > so the retrieval is constant time. But I am not able to list the merchants_id based on category for that solution. Tell me how will vector database solve this issue.

Comment: The `vector` allows for only one copy of the data records.  Search the internet for "Database Normal Forms".  Build another `std::map` for the category.

Comment: Thankyou Thomas Matthews, I already kind of know that solution. I have multimap contains  < Category , Merchant_Id> as another element.

Answer (score 0):

C++ flavor:

```
    using category_assignment = std::set<merchant_id_type>;
    std::map<std::string, category_assignment> categories;
```

(wherever you place it) will give you cheap access from the category name to the respective merchants.

Problem starts when you need it backwards ("which categories does Merchant N belong to?")

To get that you should encapsulate the map in a singleton-like class X, add a map for the reverse mapping and manage both maps through the interface of X.

Comment: U mean, separate map for categories ? and separate one for Merchant_details ?

Comment: a mapping from categories to a set of merchants, yes. at least, if not also vice-versa (btw look at boost::bimap). About the merchant "details" - if "retrieve the list of shop for a Merchant_Id" is the only relevant use case, then your related design appears ok;  per merchant instance a map or hash (c++: unordered_map) map of shop_id to shop.

Comment: For a given merchant Id, 1) I want to get the merchant details 2) list of shop_Id so it is already encapsulated into merchant details. So I will have constant time for retrieval for merchant details ( which solves 1 and 2 ) for me. But if I encapsulated categories also in merchant details, i can't solve the 3rd problem, where I need to list all the merchant Id's for a particular category

Comment: That design sketch above doesn't store cats in details; it stores merchant ids under a global cats' manager .

Comment: Thankyou decltype_auto, You and Thomas mentioned on almost same solution like having separate element for category.

Comment: That is quite mandatory from an ERM view onto the model. Btw - pls don't forget to accept one of the answers. (*Preferably mine, of course*) :)